# How to manually control ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add a legend to the `qplot` generated by this code:

```
qplot(pa1, geom = "density", fill = I("blue"), alpha = I(0.3), label = "auto") + geom_density(aes(x = pb1), fill = "red", alpha = I(0.3), label = "brand") + 
  geom_density(aes(x = ph1), fill = "green", alpha = I(0.3)) + xlab("Predicted Values") + 
  ylab("Density") + ggtitle("Auto (blue) Brand (red) and Home (green)")
```

where `pa1, pb1, ph1` are vectors of predictions from `glm` models.

The final output works: [image]

but no legend...

Comment: It would be nice if you actually posted a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) what we could run and edit for you. But the basic idea is that if you want something to show up in the legend, it should be in an `aes()`

Answer (score 0):

You might find it more simple to do this way, and the legend is there.

```
ggplot(diamonds) + geom_density(aes(x=price, colour=clarity,fill=clarity,alpha=.3))
```